# перемешивание, смещение и дублирование записей в RecyclerView при достижении определенного количество записей

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-layout

Подскажите пожалуйста, в моём приложение происходит пользовательское добавление записей в базу данных, а оттуда записи  в виде списка отображаются в RecyclerView, при количестве записей 10-15 всё работает нормально при начале перемотки (при количестве записей более 15), список начинает вести себя неадекватно: происходит смещение записей, дублирование и т.д. Подскажите что можно сделать?

---

adapter

```
    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>  {

    private String[][] mDataset;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private static final String TAG="myLogs";

    // класс view holder-а с помощью которого мы получаем ссылку на каждый элемент


    // Конструктор
    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, String[][] dataset) {

        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mDataset = dataset;
    }

    // Создает новые views (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                         int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

        // тут можно программно менять атрибуты лэйаута (size, margins, paddings и др.)

        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    // Заменяет контент отдельного view (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String a=mDataset[position][0];
        if (a.equals("")){
            Log.i(TAG, "левая сторона RecyclerView acran2_2 пусто");
            String b=mDataset[position][1];
            if (b.equals("")){
                Log.i(TAG, "правая сторона  RecyclerView acran2_2 пусто");
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "правая сторона RecyclerView acran2_2 не пусто, раскрашивание местоимения");
                Spannable spans2 = new SpannableString(b);
                final ForegroundColorSpan style1 = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
                spans2.setSpan(style1, 0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
                holder.rightView.setText(spans2);
//        holder.rightView.setText(mDataset[position][1]);
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "левая сторона RecyclerView acran2_2 не пусто, раскрашивание местоимения");
            Spannable spans = new SpannableString(a);
            final ForegroundColorSpan style = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.rgb(255, 0, 0));
            spans.setSpan(style, 0, 4, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
            holder.leftView.setText(spans);
        }

    }
    // Возвращает размер данных (вызывается layout manager-ом)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    // отдельного пункта списка
    public  class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        // наш пункт состоит только из одного TextView
        public TextView leftView;
        public TextView rightView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            leftView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.leftSms);
            rightView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.rightSms);
        }
    }
}
```

---

xml layout экрана

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Acrans.Acr.acran2_2"
    android:background="@color/colorBlue">

    <!-- A RecyclerView with some commonly used attributes -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwertyuiop"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@color/colorBlue"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvNumber"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="19sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/qwertyuiop"
        android:layout_above="@+id/qwertyuiop1"
        android:background="@color/colorBlue"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorBlue"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/qwertyuiop1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/colorBlue"
        >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/tvMessage"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="11.0"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Введите сообщение"
            android:background="@color/colorYelow"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:gravity="left"/>
        <!--<Button-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/btnSend"-->
        <!--android:layout_weight="1.0"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="0dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:text="Ок"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"/>-->
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton97"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.0"
            android:background="@drawable/hbutton"
            android:visibility="visible"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

xml RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/leftSms"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/rightSms"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:textSize="17sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: айемы переиспользуются и то, что вы видите неправильное - это то, что остается от прошлого айтема. происходит это потому, что вы биндите данные на айтем по условию и не все ветки условия устанавливают данные для конкретного айтема, в этом случае там остается то, что было ранее. тема до дыр затерта уже в том числе и на этом ресурсе, поищите готовые ответы

Comment: вам нужно устанавливать значение в виджет в обоих ветках. В вашем случае в ветке с пустым содержимым в виджет устанавливать пустое значение: `holder.rightView.setText("");`, аналогично и для левого края.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо большое, помогло)